# Javascript map returns undefined even though condition is correct and item exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
handleGetDiscussion = (discussionId) => {
    const discussionList = [...this.state.discussionList];

    console.log("The discussionList", discussionList);

    discussionList.map((discussion) => {
      if (discussion._id === discussionId) {
        return discussion;
      }
    });

    // return discussionList.filter(
    //   (discussion) => discussion._id === discussionId
    // );
  };
```

The above is a function to get a certain discussion from discussionList. Howevere for some reason, when I assign the return value to a variable such that:

```
const selectedDiscussion = this.handleGetDiscussion(discussionId);
```

it returns `undefined` from the `map` function even though the `discussion._id` and `discussionId` exist, and it is true (checked using console log) but somehow instead of returning the `discussion` , it returns `undefined`. On the other hand, if I change the `map` function to `filter`, it works. May I know what is the reason behind this?

Comment: With the `.map`, you aren't returning anything from the function. But with the `.filter`, you *are* returning the result of `.filter`

Comment: it's recommended to use forEach method rather map since forEach faster than map

Comment: Array.prototype.map creates a new collection. So you have to do `const newList = discussionList.map(...)`

Comment: Yes, because your function is not returning anything. In javascript if you don't return anything it is the same as returning undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
handleGetDiscussion = (discussionId) => {
  const discussionList = [...this.state.discussionList];
  let result;


  discussionList.forEach((discussion) => {
    if (discussion._id === discussionId) {
      result = discussion;
    }
  });

  return result;
};
```

Comment: Im pretty sure the array spread doesn't need to be done since there is no mutation to the list.

Comment: @HanYolo The array copy is probably too much.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is not returning anything which is the same as returning undefined:

```
  handleGetDiscussion = (discussionId) => {
    const discussionList = [...this.state.discussionList];

    console.log("The discussionList", discussionList);

    discussionList.map((discussion) => {
      if (discussion._id === discussionId) {
        return discussion;
      }
    });

    // return discussionList.filter(
    //   (discussion) => discussion._id === discussionId
    // );

    // not returning anything therefore this is the same
    // as returning undefined!
  };
```

The `return` inside `map` is for the `(discussion) => {` function, not `handleGetDiscussion = (discussionId) => {`:

```
  handleGetDiscussion = (discussionId) => {
    const discussionList = [...this.state.discussionList];

    console.log("The discussionList", discussionList);

    discussionList.map((discussion) => { <---------------. The return                 
      if (discussion._id === discussionId) {             | belongs to
        return discussion;     --------------------------' this function
      }
    });

    // return discussionList.filter(
    //   (discussion) => discussion._id === discussionId
    // );
  };
```

If your intention is to just return the first found discussion you need to use a regular `for` or `while` loop:

```
  handleGetDiscussion = (discussionId) => {
    const discussionList = [...this.state.discussionList];

    console.log("The discussionList", discussionList);

    for (let i=0; i< discussionList.length; i++) {
      let discussion = discussionList[i];                 
      if (discussion._id === discussionId) {
        return discussion;
      }
    }

  };
```

You cannot really replace it with `forEach` because you will have the same issue using the `return` keyword:

```
  handleGetDiscussion = (discussionId) => {
    const discussionList = [...this.state.discussionList];

    console.log("The discussionList", discussionList);

    // WILL NOT WORK:

    discussionList.forEach((discussion) => { <-----------. The return                 
      if (discussion._id === discussionId) {             | belongs to
        return discussion;     --------------------------' this function
      }
    });
  }
```

But there is a way to do it functionally - using `find`:

```
  handleGetDiscussion = (discussionId) => {
    const discussionList = [...this.state.discussionList];

    console.log("The discussionList", discussionList);

    return discussionList.find((discussion) => {                 
      return discussion._id === discussionId;
    });
  }
```

Comment: @DominiqueFortin If you read the full answer there are two possibilities - in the part after I say `you need to use a regular for or while loop` and at the end

Comment: when we return the discussion in that forEach function or map function , what will happen? because it seems that even if it hit the return statement, it will still continue the mapping process

Comment: It returns to the map. The `map` will then take that return result and collect it into an array which would then be returned by the map function to you

Answer (score 1):

`find()` is the way to find a single match (if ids are unique) or the first one of several matches (if ids aren't unique).  If the ids aren't unique and you want to find all matches, then `filter()` is the right way.

```js
let discussionList = [{
  id: 1,
  content: "discussion one"
}, {
  id: 2,
  content: "discussion two"
}, {
  id: 3,
  content: "discussion three"
}, {
  id: 1,
  content: "another discussion with id one"
}]

function discussionWithId(id) {
  return discussionList.find(d => d.id === id)
}

function discussionsWithId(id) {
  return discussionList.filter(d => d.id === id)
}

console.log(discussionWithId(2))
console.log(discussionsWithId(1))
```